# How to rename and add incrementing number suffix on multiple files in Batch Script?

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have 500 files coming in and I need to first check if any file(s) exist then rename all of them regardless of what their filename is (the files are named in a different language).

No need to process them in any order.

**Rename:**

```
1.  “¦X¼d¬f-20110703-¦+¦dñHÑ-ª-¦=¬¦.xls” 
2.  “¦X¼d¬f-20110707-¦+¡¦-+¡8.xls”
3.  “¦X¼d¬f-20110707-¦+¡¦ñj¦«.xls”
4.  “¦X¼d¬f-20110708-¦+¡¦¬M¼n.xls”
5.  “¦X¼d¬f-20110713-¦d¼O¼n¦hÑP.xls”
.
.
.
500
```

**To:**

```
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_01.xls”
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_02.xls”
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_03.xls”
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_04.xls”
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_05.xls”
.
.
.
“TWN_CH_INV_VISIT_FORM_500.xls”
```

Hope you could help me on this one. I’ve been trying to do this for weeks.

Comment: powershell? or cmd? or something else?

Comment: what have you tried for weeks so far? what problems did you find? a simple `FOR` with a count (`SET /A`) should do what you need. See `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET`

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515453/issues-with-enabledelayedexpansion-for-file-renaming-batch-script

Answer (score 6):

a simple `FOR` with a count (`SET /A`) should do what you need.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A COUNT=0
FOR %%A IN (*.xls) DO (
  SET /A COUNT+=1
  REN "%%A" "TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_!COUNT!.xls"
)
```

See `HELP FOR` and `HELP SET`

Comment: Thanks! It did the job, but missed 1 file. Out of 14 files, all have been renamed except for TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_7.xls

Comment: There are some serious problems with this answer. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37239631/1012053) for more information, as well as a robust solution

Answer (score 1):

This is a deceptively difficult question to solve.

The 5 year old PA answer has a few problems.

1) The FOR loop begins iterating without buffering the entire directory tree, so it has the potential to rename a file that has already been renamed. I believe that is why the 7 file is missing within r0mmel's comment.

2) Delayed expansion occurs after for variables are expanded, so the file name will be corrupted and the rename will fail if the name contains a `!` character.

3) A rename can fail if there already exists a TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_n.xls file with the same number.

At first I thought I could solve the problem using the following:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in (
  'dir /b *.xls ^| findstr /n "^"'
) do ren "%%B" "TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_%%A.xls.new"
ren *.txt.new *.
```

I use DIR /B to list the files, and pipe that result to FINDSTR to prefix each file name with a line number, followed by a colon.

I then use FOR /F to iterate and parse the results into the number and the file name. FOR /F buffers the entire result before iterating, so I don't need to worry about renaming the same file twice.

I first give the renamed files a `.xls.new` "extension", just in case your directory already has files that meet the `TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_n.xls` pattern. You don't want any name collisions. The final REN command then simply removes the `.new` extension to leave the desired `.xls`.

***BUT***, I just noticed that the original file names have lots of weird characters that could involve unicode that is not in the current code page. FOR /F does not play well with unicode.

There is one other minor issue in that the above does not pad the number to a fixed width. (this could have been solved easily enough)

So at this point it is time to break out my [JREN.BAT regular expression renaming utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6081). It is pure script (hybrid batch / JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. It has a built in facility to incorporate a fixed width incrementing number in the new name, and it works fine with unicode. I still temporarily give the new name the ".xls.new" extension to avoid any name collisions.

```
@echo off
call jren "^.*" "'TWN_CH_INV_VIST_FORM_'+$n+'.xls.new'" /j /npad 3 /fm *.xls
ren *.xls.new *.
```

I chose to pad the incrementing number to 3 digits instead of 2 because the OP said there could be 500 files.

Full documentation for JREN.BAT is available from the command line via `jren /?`, or `jren /??` if you want paged output.