# How to add incrementing number prefix order by date on multiple files in Batch Script?

Tags: shell, batch-file, window

I'm using window OS, and I downloaded video as series lesson. I would like order those videos by date and adding prefix number for first video as 1 than 2, 3..... I found answer at here [How to rename and add incrementing number suffix on multiple files in Batch Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691455/how-to-rename-and-add-incrementing-number-suffix-on-multiple-files-in-batch-scri/6692639#6692639) it can add number to filename, but can only order by name not date. Thank and sorry for my English.

Comment: With `dir /O` you can list files sorted by date (see `dir /?` for options); you could parse its output by a `for /F` loop, install a counter variable and prepend it to the file names by `ren`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implementation of what aschipfl suggested in his comment:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /a n=0
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /od') do (
  set /a n+=1
  ren "%%F" "!n!_%%F"
)
```

But there are two potential problems:

1) The FOR /F command has a default EOL character of `;` - if a file name were to start with `;`, then it would be skipped. The simple solution is to set EOL to a character that cannot appear in a file name - `:` is a good choice.

2) The rename will fail if a filename contains a `!` character because delayed expansion is enabled, and `%%F` is expanded before delayed expansion. The solution is to save the file name to a variable, and then toggle delayed expansion ON and OFF within the loop

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a n=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /od') do (
  set "file=%%F"
  set /a n+=1
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!file!" "!n!_!file!"
  endlocal
)
```

There is a simpler option - use `FINDSTR /N` to prefix the `DIR /B /OD` output with the line number, and then use `FOR /F` to parse out the number and the file name. Now there is no need for a counter variable or delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('dir /b /od ^| findstr /n "^"') do ren "%%B" "%%A_%%B"
```

You don't even need a batch file. You could use the following directly from the command line:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %A in ('dir /b /od ^| findstr /n "^"') do ren "%B" "%A_%B"
```