# (Use a batch file) Get the filename only into a For loop

Tags: batch-file

***This is the new version according to your comments.***
***It still doesn't work.***

I try to rename files like

- 2006 Gaspésie - Croisière à la baleine 1023.jpg
- 2006 Gaspésie - Croisière baleine 28.jpg

To

- 2006-06 Croisière baleine 001.jpg
- 2006-06 Croisière baleine 002.jpg

The problem is that the fields F1 and F2 are empty when I do echo and when I do rename.

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /p "NewFileName=New name file (without the extension): "
set /p "LenghtMask=Mask lenght of the number: "
set /a FileNo=0

for %%I in (*.JPG) do (
echo.

@echo off
set /a FileNo=!FileNo!+1
call :return_no_mask !FileNo! %LenghtMask% FileNoMask
@echo on

set "F1=%%~I"
echo F1   %F1%

set ExtensionName=%%~xI
set "F2=%NewFileName% %FileNoMask%%ExtensionName%"
echo F2   %F2%

rename "%F1%" "%F2%"
pause
)
goto:EOF


::--------------------------------------------------
::Return the number (fill with 0 to have the right lenght)
:: in  Number to use
:: in  Mask's lenght ex: 2
:: out Number
::--------------------------------------------------
:return_no_mask
set NoIn=%1

::---Search the lenght of the number
set /a LenghtNo=1
if "%NoIn%" GEQ "10" set /a LenghtNo=2
if "%NoIn%" GEQ "100" set /a LenghtNo=3
if "%NoIn%" GEQ "1000" set /a LenghtNo=4
if "%NoIn%" GEQ "10000" set /a LenghtNo=5

::---Fill with zero
set NoOut=
:test_add
if "%LenghtNo%" LSS "%2" (
set NoOut=0%NoOut%
set /a LenghtNo+=1
goto :test_add
)
set NoOut=%NoOut%%1

set %3=%NoOut%
EXIT /B 0

::--------------------------------------------------
::End of file
::--------------------------------------------------
:EOF
endlocal
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename and add incrementing number suffix on multiple files in Batch Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691455/how-to-rename-and-add-incrementing-number-suffix-on-multiple-files-in-batch-scri)

Comment: So you enabled delayed expansion but chose not to use it?

Comment: What also does not make sense is you are assigning the file extension to a variable named tmp and then trying to replace spaces in that variable. That will never happen because there are no spaces in the file extension. You are also using the variable tmp and %%~xI in the CALL which doesn't make any sense. Also tmp is a system variable. I would advise you pick a different variable name.

Comment: By `set Tmp=%%xI` you actually mean `set Tmp=%%~xI`, right?

Comment: I have updated the post.